# Javascript and wordpress page load

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Am working on a website techhouse.ng. My problem is that I have a javascript that changes the width and color of certain divs when the menu li links (services and contact) are clicked. The script works fine but the problem is that by the time the page loads the divs reverts back to the default settings.

I created page-service.php and page-contact.php for those links. but the script works on the index.php, so when you click on either the services link or the contact links the script works but by the time the page loads the divs revert back to their original css values.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

 $("#li-12").click(function () {
 $("#rcolumn").css("width", '25%');
$("#rcolumn").css("background-color", 'rgb(44, 62, 80)');
$(".wrapper").css("background-color", 'rgb(44, 62, 80)');
$(".nav li a").css("padding", '15px 0');
$(".nav li a").css("color", '#909090');
$(".nav li a").css("background", 'white');
$("#lcolumn").css("width", '75%');
$(".nav").css("width", '75%');
});

$("#li-13").click(function () {
$("#rcolumn").css("width", '25%');
$("#rcolumn").css("background-color", 'rgb(44, 62, 80)');
$(".wrapper").css("background-color", 'rgb(44, 62, 80)');
$(".nav li a").css("padding", '15px 0');
$(".nav li a").css("color", '#909090');
$(".nav li a").css("background", 'white');
$("#lcolumn").css("width", '75%');
$(".nav").css("width", '75%');
}); 

});
```

Comment: If you mean those links open a new page where you're not running this jquery script.. then that's normal. Make sure it's included in all pages.

Comment: You've got a broken link to menufx2.js. Not sure if that's the problem but it's always easier to fix the things you know aren't working - process of elimination.

Comment: @yezzz how do i include it on all pages?

Comment: umm I think the index.php so rereading your question your already doing that... are you using those 2 php files as stand-alone links, or are you using them as wordpress page templates?

Comment: @DanielMurphy who are you replying to?

Comment: @yezzz - I was replying to Joseph

Comment: lol yeah sorry, I should have said, where do you see this broken link?

Comment: @yezzz - no broken js files now. Joseph must have fixed.

Comment: @yezzz am using 2 php files as page templates. the problem is when a visitor lands on the home and then click either of the 2 links the javascript works but when the page finishs loadin it reverts back to the default css values. I want the page to keep the values that the script changed

Comment: Ok, in the meantime I found the templates are not related to the problem. There is a 404 on your services page though. As for your js/jquery code, why use the click on a link to change the styling? Do you want the "zoomed menu" shown on the services and contact page, but not on the home page?

Comment: @yezzz yes I want the "zoomed menu" shown on the services and contact page, but not on the home page

Answer (score 0):

First, you can combine multiple selectors like this: `$("#li-12, #li-13")` so your can remove a lot of duplicate code.

Second, to get the styling on those 2 pages you could put the .css stuff inside a named function and call it... though it's far from ideal, as it will have to wait until jquery framework is loaded, meaning the user will first see the default style until jQuery kicks in. It could be done using pure javascript which would fire sooner. A lot better would be to put style tags on those 2 templates, to override the default styles. Or use classes to do stuff.

But if you don't mind the delay you could do something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) { //.ready

  function altStyling() {
    $("#rcolumn").css("width", '25%');
    $("#rcolumn, .wrapper").css("background-color", 'rgb(44, 62, 80)');
    $(".nav li a").css("padding", '15px 0');
    $(".nav li a").css("color", '#909090');
    $(".nav li a").css("background", 'white');
    $("#lcolumn, .nav").css("width", '75%');
  }

  // click menu items
  $("#li-12, #li-13").click(altStyling);

  // call if we're on services or contact page
  if (location.pathname == "/services/" || location.pathname == "/contact/") altStyling();
});
```